# SoftLayer Object Storage Logs via Customer Portal?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working on an C++ application which connects to SoftLayer via the Object Storage API, and transfers files back and forth.  For almost every file transfer, the application works fine.

However, one customer reports an issue with one file transfer to SoftLayer, where the transfer seems stall after at least one chunk is sent.  As far as I can tell, the process seems to hang on a socket send call to the SoftLayer server.

I'd like to look at a log from the SoftLayer side, to see what the server sees.  I don't have good access to the customer, so I have to give them directions for what to look for and send the data to me, so I'd like to access the logs through the SoftLayer Customer Portal.

With our one test SoftLayer account, however, I can't find any logs on the Customer Portal.  Are there any?  If so, where can one find the logs?

If the logs are not available through the Customer Portal, are there some logs somewhere of what files were transferred and when?  If so, how can one get access to said logs?

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is not logs in the portal, maybe softlayer stores the logs (but I think is not probably). Anyway I suggest you to submit an issue about object storage in softlayer for further help.

Regards

Comment: SoftLayer customer support directed me here, I'll try filing a support ticket.

Comment: I Guess you submitted your issue with the subject Dev Api, if that the case they alwayas will direct you here, yes please try support tickext, because using Api is not possible to get the logs.